# Why "this.todos = [...this.todos, todo] " and not push?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

( Sorry for the simple question but I didn't know how to search on `[...]`)

I'm not a Javascript hero but I am not a beginner either. I saw the code below in a [tutorial](https://www.taniarascia.com/javascript-mvc-todo-app/) and didn't understand why `push` wasn't used – or what that syntax is called.

```
  addTodo(todo) {
    this.todos = [...this.todos, todo]
  }
```

---

Why not just:

```
  addTodo(todo) {
    this.todos.push(todo)
  }
```

Comment: property spread notation

Comment: It's replacement rather than mutation, so change detection works correctly.

Comment: and why not `this.todos = [...this.todos, todo]`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax    `[...this.todos, todo]` create a new array, the original array go to the garbage collector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a few reasons for the general case. If it's used with a setter, it'll trigger that, possibly causing side effects. If there's another reference to the array, it won't modify that like it otherwise would.

In this specific case, it's the former. We're triggering an update on the DOM by using the setter.

Answer (score 1):

If you just pushed, then the page wouldn't update. Reassigning the variable using spread notation allows the change observer to see the change and update the page.